# Dystopian movie with thousands of vagrants in a barren flat outdoor

Tags: story-identification, movie, dystopia

I remember myself watching in the mid-80s, on TV, a kind of dystopian movie in black and white. I know that there was sound but don't remember any dialogue. Here are extracts of the only two scenes that I remember from it:

- There was a barren flat outdoor with thousands of vagrants, like hobos. The weather was very cold but icy and all of them in rags were jumping repeatedly to warm themselves up. They were waiting for the clouds to part and let a brilliant sun burst forth to touch the ground, then, those hobos (like fifty) closest to the small sunny spot ran to it for warmth, then, shortly after the ray disappeared and all the fifty hobos started to jump again waiting for the next sunburst.
- One of the vagrants (like the main character) walks among other vagrants and sympathize with those who have physical defects by mimicking them (limping to a lame guy and winking the eye to a one-eyed guy).

Comment: It's not obvious what is sci-fi/fantasy about this. Was this "ice age" caused by some kind of climate change catastrophe or something?

Comment: No climate change catastrophe, at least as I recall. I believe this movie belongs to the realm of fantasy by having these things (thousands of hobos jumping all together like in a rock concert) seemingly impossible or improbable.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't see how thousands of people jumping at the same time makes it fantasy.

Comment: It sounds a bit more like an artsy flick, like a Jodorowsky film, rather than sci-fi, unless it's both, like those weird asylum scenes from THX-1138.

Comment: The fact that it's a dystopian world where people act weird is sufficient for me to vote to reopen.

Comment: This question would be improved by going through the checklists here; [How to ask a good story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is Vittorio De Sica's delightful [Miracle in Milan](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0043809/) from 1951.

> An open hearted and unrelentingly energetic orphan struggles to make the best out of his life on the streets of Milan.

It takes place in a shantytown and both scenes are there. The first, with the vagrants hopping in place to keep warm and huddling together to enjoy a beam of sunshine, is somewhat well-known. In the second one, the young protagonist (Toto) sees a man hunched over with a bad back and pretends his back hurts too, then sees an old man with a weak eye and closes one of his in solidarity.

And it's a fantasy tale, so it does belong here IMO. After all, Toto was born in a cabbage, has a magic dove that grants wishes (which he got from a ghost), and the movie ends

> with people flying around on broomsticks.

Here's the scene with the vagrants:

Comment: Bravo Walt! Two of my questions answered in a row. Thank you very much.